# MySQL and Hibernate Simultaneous read write

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, transactions, load

I have a web application which has the following parts:

1. Commentators continuously doing match commentary through a browser based tool. The comments are inserted into DB using hibernat.
2. Lots of users are accessing a URL to read commentary. Hibernate is reading data from the table being updated by commentators in step #1.
3. There are some stored procedures as well which are set to run every 1 hour. Few of them access the same table (used in step #1 and #2) for reading and writing/updating purpose.

Now my problem is, whenever the site has 100+ concurrent users watching a particular match commentary, my MySQL goes down. It shows lots of queries stuck in processlist. Many of them are in *"Copying to temp table"* state.  This makes the JBOSS restart frequently.

I am using transactions in hibernate for both reading and writing purposes. Please help because I loose big matches because of these crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You have a performance problem. It is difficult to give solutions which always work. What you can consider to do is:

1) Revise the HQL (Hibernate) statements. For this best you write a protocol with `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in the config file (or even a tool like log4jdbc if you want to see the actual parameters) and analyse the output. There you see which SQL requests you have most. In many cases a better strategy for reading and writing db data can significantly reduce the database traffic. And check you have good indexes for your table.

2) Consider to use a second level cache. (Normally hibernate only uses the first level cache, which is of no use in your case because it is bound to one session.) Then at least the requests for reading actual commentaries can be served by the cache and don't need to go to the database. (Pay attention: The cache might interfere with the stored procedures. Have a look if the cache product you like to use supports MySQL stored procedures. In the worst case you have to remove the stored procedures for the critical tables and let you application server do the job so it goes through the cache.)

3) If it is only a few tables which are heavily used you can consider to cache them by your application. That's more work, but perhaps you can do it exactly for the demands of your application, so you might be faster than with a general second level cache.

4) If nothing helps and the traffic is really too heavy then perhaps you have to invest in more hardware.

Good luck ;-)

Comment: For 400 concurrent users on site, the linux system works fine at an uptime of 1.x. But whenever some scheduled stored procedure runs(targeting the same table), the uptime shoots past 20 and crashes mysql. Manyatimes I have also encountered mysql showing processlist with too many processes but all in sleep mode !!!

Comment: A stored procedure can lock resources (here table columns) which might interfere with your web application, i. e. its services. Can you post one stored procedure which let the database crash? By the way, which engine do you use for the tables?

Comment: I am using innodb. stored procedure is just reading rows from the table having column dirty_bit = 1 and then does some inserts in other table and sets the dirty_bit = 0. It runs every minute and most of the time dirty_bit is 0 so does not do any insert/updates.

Comment: The procedure has to lock the row so it can set the column dirty_bit. It might happen the procedure also locks rows which it does not set (do you have 'select for update'?). For test purposes you can try to remove the update of that column. How much does the select in the procedure need? If there is no index, running that select once a minute might be too often.

Comment: Can it happen, the procedure is started a second time before the procedure call before terminated? Can it happen the stored procedure has to wait for other  processes to release the table locks (in which case its execution needs longer time)? For tests try to start the stored procedures only once an hour.